# How to do a nested sum with multiplication in gurobi python for a MILP problem

Tags: python, nested, constraints, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I am new to python and I have started doing optimization using gurobi in python.

I am stuck at writing the first constraint.

I have searched multiple documentation but unable to find it.

It is nested sum for multiple items using multiplication.

Can anyone help me in the same?

Thanks in advance.

```
[This is the constraint I am trying to formulate][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkzLa.jpg
```

Comment: Hi @Margi Shah can you provide your data and desired output for better understanding

Comment: How can I write a equation over here?

Comment: I have attached a image (link in post) of the equation I want to formulate .